# Python code repetition for key to kill program

Tags: python, repeat

I have created a talk-bot with the main program as below.
I need to be able to cancel the program with the "Return"-button, which is why I have the "if len() > X" below.
Although, I think it is code repetition and will fail if I don't find a 
way to do the code without code repetition. Does anyone have a suggestion of how I can finish my program without code repetition?

```
name = input("Hello, I'm Talky! What's your name?\n")
if len(name) > 0:
    answer = input("Nice to meet you, " + name + "! What is your problem?\n").lower().replace("!", "").replace("?", "")
    if len(answer) > 0:
        user = User(name)
        while True:
            answer = reader.replace(answer)
            answer = user.conversation(answer)
            if len(answer) < 1: 
                break
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
while len(answer) > 1:
    # ...
```